# Add connection using Google/Facebook account to a JavaEE application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Is it possible to add the "Connect using Google/Facebook" feature to a JavaEE system on top of the security module provided by JavaEE standard?
I don't want to internally handle user's login data, but still have some privileges mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using frameworks like `Spring`, you may try [Spring Social](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/). `Spring social` has lot of options for social integration.

If you don't want to use `Spring` framework, you may try third part libraries like [Social Auth](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/).